# How come my code is still printing out numbers when I specify only letters to be printed?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is a sample value
hash=d7dd933b5bb968b6ba9ee40548b1b27a

# retrieve all letters from this hash
count=0
for (( i=0; i<${#hash}; i++)); do
   if [[ ${hash:i:1} == [a-f] ]] ; then
     code[$count]=${hash:i:1}    
     count=$((count + 1))
     echo ${code[i]}
     #echo ${hash:i:1}
   fi
done
```

Instead of printing all characters in the hash (as I expect), this is printing only the first two characters, followed by newlines. (Eventually, I intend to take only the first two characters extracted from `hash`, but this is not an immediate goal).

What's wrong here?

Comment: In the future, your code samples should contain only the minimal content necessary to reproduce a problem -- so not your whole program, but only the parts you're using to eliminate numbers / print only letters. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to filter out all the letters from the hash string, you can modify your `for` loop as follows:

```
code=()
count=0
for (( i = 0; i < ${#hash}; i++ )); do
    if [[ ${hash:i:1} == [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
        code[$count]="${hash:i:1}"
        ((count++))
    fi
done
```

Here, `${hash:i:1}` selects each character in hash individually. If the character is in the range of letters `a-zA-Z`, meaning it is a letter, then it is stored in the array `code`, and `count` is accumulated.

---

Consider the following full code as an example (assume it is contained in a file called `script`):

```
#!/bin/bash

hash="$1"                      # $1 means first argument given to this script file
printf "hash = %s\n" "$hash"

code=()                        # initialize code array
count=0
for (( i = 0; i < ${#hash}; i++ )); do
    if [[ ${hash:i:1} == [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
        code[$count]="${hash:i:1}"
        ((count++))
    fi
done

printf "All letters are: "
printf "%s" "${code[@]}"
printf "\n"

printf "First two letters are: %c%c \n" "${code[0]}" "${code[1]}"
```

Tests:

```
$ ./script dd7d933b5bb968b6ba9ee40548b1b27a
hash = dd7d933b5bb968b6ba9ee40548b1b27a
All letters are: dddbbbbbaeebba
First two letters are: dd
$ ./script slfj2948347slddkshfsl2348sldfjsf
hash = slfj2948347slddkshfsl2348sldfjsf
All letters are: slfjslddkshfslsldfjsf
First two letters are: sl
```

Comment: This certainly works, but it's a much less efficient approach than a parameter expansion that removes all numbers from a string in a single pass. Is there a reason for making the loop explicit?

Comment: I updated OP's `for` loop because he stated that it did not work the way he wanted, but parameter expansion certainly works in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) provides numerous string-manipulation primitives, including search-and-replace, which can be readily used for this purpose:

```
s=1a2b3c4d5e6f7g
code=${s//[![:alpha:]]/}
echo "$code"
```

...should emit:

```
abcdefg
```

...if you wanted to emit only the first two characters in `code`, that would be:

```
echo "${code:0:2}"
```

---

#### Why this works

- `[:alpha:]` is a POSIX character class which includes characters consider alphabet members in the current locale.
- `[![:alpha:]]` is a glob expression which matches any single character not in that class
- `${var//value/replacement}` expands the variable named `var`, changing all instances of `value` to `replacement`
- Thus, `${s//[![:alpha:]]/}` expands the variable `s`, changing all characters which are not alphabetic in nature to the empty string.

Comment: And using sed `echo $hash | sed -e 's/[^a-f]//g'` .

Comment: @Mort, that's slower than the PE approach, and actually buggier -- `echo "$hash"` would be fine (sorta -- `echo` has its own problems, but none of them apply within the range of possible values of `$hash` here), but `echo $hash` (without the quotes) will change any characters found in your hash that are in the IFS variable to spaces.

Comment: @Mort, ...so, if you had, say, `IFS=0`, and `hash=abc0f34`, then `echo $hash` would print `abc f34`.

Comment: You're right. I should have put the quotes in, although for this case, it's an MD5sum. I come from a tradition of being suspicious of bash-isms which keeps me away from the admittedly useful parameter expansion tools. :-)

Comment: @Mort, sure, that's why I gave an example only using characters in `[0-9a-f]`. :)